# Getting a NA for sum across rows if any variable values is NA

Tags: r

I have a dataset with var1, var2, var3, var4, and I am calculating a sum `var_total \<- var1 + var2 + var3 + var4`. I want missing value in var_total if any of the values var1,
var2, var3 and var4 is missing.

Have:

| Var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 | var_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | NA | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | NA | 1 |

Want:

| Var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 | var_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | NA | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | NA | NA |

I assume something involving `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Data

```
data <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4, ~var_total,
    1L,    0L,    0L,    0L,         1L,
    1L,    NA,    2L,    0L,         3L,
    1L,    0L,    0L,    NA,         1L
  )
```

#### Code

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var_total = sum(c_across(cols = var1:var4),na.rm = FALSE))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
   var1  var2  var3  var4 var_total
  <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1     1     0     0     0         1
2     1    NA     2     0        NA
3     1     0     0    NA        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums()` in base R:

```
data$var_total <- rowSums(data[ , 1:4])
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(var_total = rowSums(across(var1:var4)))
```

Result from either approach:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var_total
1    1    0    0    0         1
2    1   NA    2    0        NA
3    1    0    0   NA        NA
```

Comment: sorry, but any chance you could tell me - how would I refer to the variables if they have names like x y z instead of var1, var2, var3? I am too much of a noob to know how to translate the "var1:var4" part

Comment: For the dplyr approach, `var1:var4` is just taking all columns in your dataset from `var1` on the left to `var4` on the right. So if you instead have columns `x`, `y`, and `z`, you would do `across(x:z)` if they're all right next to each other. If not, and there are variables between them you don't want included, you could do `across(c(x, y, z))`. This is all based on the tidyselect selection language, by the way; see [the docs](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) for more details and other options.

Comment: Ah, it's the "c" that means combine values into a vector, I get it now, thanks!